# Mysql local variable is not updating

Tags: mysql

I try to use local variable in order to save the value for user count in order to calculate the ratio between the current count and the one before.

I use this query:

```
SET @count = 0;

SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(ual.time, "%M, %Y") as monthName,

@count as beforeCount, 

count(DISTINCT ual.user_id)/@count as progress,

@count := count(DISTINCT ual.user_id) as afterCount

FROM user_activity_log ual

LEFT OUTER JOIN user u

ON u.gym = 22

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ualWeek.user_id FROM user_activity_log ualWeek 

GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(ualWeek.time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(ualWeek.time) -1, 7)), ualWeek.user_id 

HAVING count(ualWeek.user_id) > 1) weekUsers

ON u.id = weekUsers.user_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ualMonth.user_id FROM user_activity_log ualMonth 

GROUP BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(ualMonth.time, "%Y-%m-01")), ualMonth.user_id 

HAVING count(ualMonth.user_id) > 5) monthUsers

ON u.id = monthUsers.user_id

WHERE

(ual.user_id = weekUsers.user_id OR ual.user_id = monthUsers.user_id) AND

((ual.time BETWEEN '2014-02-13' AND '2015-02-13') OR (('2014-02-13' IS NULL) OR ('2015-02-13' IS NULL)))

GROUP BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(ual.time, "%Y-%m-01"))
```

My problem is that `@count`does not update himself.
This is my result:
[image]

If I edit my query and remove my joins its working fine.
The new query:

```
SET @count = 0;

SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(ual.time, "%M, %Y") as monthName,

@count as beforeCount, 

count(DISTINCT ual.user_id)/@count as progress,

@count := count(DISTINCT ual.user_id) as afterCount

FROM user_activity_log ual

WHERE

((ual.time BETWEEN '2014-02-13' AND '2015-02-13') OR (('2014-02-13' IS NULL) OR ('2015-02-13' IS NULL)))

GROUP BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(ual.time, "%Y-%m-01"))
```

[image]

- My question is why does is happen and how can I keep my joins and still have my `@counter`

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of user-defined variables is *not guaranteed* with a SELECT statement, the way you are using it.

Excerpt from Section "9.4 User-Defined Variables" of the **MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual**

> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:
>
> `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;`
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html

---

You can try (no guarantees) wrapping your SELECT with the joins in parens, and using that as an inline view for another query. Up through version 5.5 at least, the results from that query are materialized as a derived table, and the outer query runs against that.

The approach is to get the resultset prepared into a derived table, and then run an outer query that makes use of the user-defined variable, to "preserve" the value from the previous row. Again, no guarantees, but this may work for you:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.dt, '%M, %Y') AS monthName
     , d.cnt/@prev_count           AS progress
     , @prev_count := d.cnt        AS cnt
  FROM ( SELECT @prev_count := 0 ) i
  JOIN ( SELECT DATE(DATE_FORMAT(ual.time, '%Y-%m-01')) AS dt  
              , COUNT(DISTINCT ual.user_id)             AS cnt
           FROM user_activity_log ual
           LEFT 
           JOIN user u
             ON u.gym = 22
           LEFT 
           JOIN ( SELECT ualWeek.user_id 
                    FROM user_activity_log ualWeek 
                   GROUP
                      BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(ualWeek.time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(ualWeek.time) -1, 7))
                       , ualWeek.user_id 
                  HAVING COUNT(ualWeek.user_id) > 1
                ) weekUsers
             ON weekUsers.user_id = u.id
           LEFT 
           JOIN ( SELECT ualMonth.user_id
                    FROM user_activity_log ualMonth 
                   GROUP
                      BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(ualMonth.time, '%Y-%m-01'))
                       , ualMonth.user_id
                  HAVING COUNT(ualMonth.user_id) > 5
                ) monthUsers
             ON monthUsers.user_id = u.id
          WHERE (ual.user_id = weekUsers.user_id OR ual.user_id = monthUsers.user_id)
            AND ((ual.time BETWEEN '2014-02-13' AND '2015-02-13') OR (('2014-02-13' IS NULL) OR ('2015-02-13' IS NULL)))
          GROUP BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(ual.time, '%Y-%m-01'))
          ORDER BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(ual.time, '%Y-%m-01'))
       ) d
```